# Generation has Thrown an Exception (no explanation aftarwards):

Tags: rigify

I have no clue what I've done to cause this error, the possible solutions that I have found (clearing unused files and trying to find a broken bone) have not worked. all I know that there is an issue with the face bones. I'll leave the .blend file for anyone to look at and share their opinion on this issue of mine.
[(google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16z2HNadUdGRh4jjXBnHgiAYEMQ3dUKJe/view?usp=sharing).
Apron the recommendation from Duarte here is a small clip of my issue
[image: the issue]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: If you open the System Console from Blender's Window > Toggle System Console menu and generate the rig again you'll see a much more detailed report of the error which appears to involve the 'cheek.T.L' bone being claimed by a duplicate rig. I assume this is something to do with the way that Rigify works, but someone else here is more likely to recognise the problem than me..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the type for the top cheek bone and I removed the brow glue as well. thanks for the help. that system console is very helpful.